# Import tries to import a different file than I specified

Tags: python, eclipse, file, import

I had a file called baseFunctions.py which I changed to elementFunctions.py. Importing elementFunctions with parsePeaksMzML.py gave me weird print statements, especially because I did not have any print statements in elementFunctions.py. Stepping through the code with Eclipses debugger showed instead of doing

```
import elementFunctions
```

as it said in the parsePeaksMzML.py, it actually did

```
import baseFunctions
```

I thought there was some weird mix-up with the renaming, so I copied all the code from elementFunctions.py, deleted the file, made a new file and pasted in all the code in the new file. Still I got the same weird errors. Looking in the folder I still had the baseFunctions.pyc, so I deleted that. Rerunning the code gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homes/ndeklein/workspace/MS/Trunk/PyMS_dev/pyMS/test/test_parsePeaksMzML.py", line 25, in <module>
    import parsePeaksMzML
  File "/homes/ndeklein/workspace/MS/Trunk/PyMS_dev/pyMS/test/parsePeaksMzML.py", line 12, in <module>
    import elementFunctions
ImportError: No module named baseFunctions
```

Somehow import elementFunctions points to import baseFunctions (I have no clue why) and deleting and remaking elementFunctions.py has no effect. I can't find anything like this searching on google or stack overflow, so I'm kind of stumped here.

I suspect it to be a problem with eclipse, but I'm not sure.

---

edit:
What makes it even stranger, I get the error when I import parsePeaksMzML.py from 
test_parsePeaksMzML.py, but not when I run parsePeaksMzML.py directly.

edit2:
Running from the commandline gives the same error:

```
-bash-3.2$ python test_parsePeaksMzML.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_parsePeaksMzML.py", line 26, in <module>
    import parsePeaksMzML
  File "/homes/ndeklein/workspace/MS/Trunk/PyMS_dev/pyMS/test/parsePeaksMzML.py", line  12, in <module>

ImportError: No module named baseFunctions
-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Post what happens after you Project / Clean in your Eclipse IDE.

Comment: You can test whether the IDE is responsible by running the code independently.  Please report the result; then we know whether to troubleshoot your IDE or your imports.

Comment: I put the results under edit2, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the name of a file, probably you have some old .pyc lingering in your workspace. I'm assuming you're using the PyDev plug-in in Eclipse; I haven't used it in a while, but you should be able to do a Project -> Clean. If that doesn't help, try manually clearing all of the .pyc files in your workspace.

The symptoms you describe are very strange, so I'm not 100% sure what the problem is. Regardless, trying cleaning your workspace and let us know how things progress from there.

Comment: First I changed the name of the file, but when it was not working I copied the code, deleted the file, and put the code in a newly made file. I removed all the .pyc files from the folder and cleaned the built, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: had a parsePeaksMzML.pyc file somewhere in a folder where I did not look (still have no idea why it was there or why that one got imported), deleting that solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do try a blanket delete of all `.pyc` files and see if that clears it up.  If not, here are a few possibilities:

- Your `$PYTHONPATH` points to different source than you expect.  (Though this would likely not be the entire explanation.)
- Code within `elementFunctions/__init__.py` is trying to import `baseFunctions`.
- Code somewhere is using an `exec` statement to do imports, or using the built-in `__import__` function to dynamically import `baseFunctions` (which might make the source of the directive difficult to hunt down).